# Are email addresses and (unprotected) contact forms on websites a security-/spamer risk?

Tags: security, captcha, spam-prevention, email-spam

I could not find a clear answer to this question. I am looking for some up to date best-practice advice for the following two topics:

1. Displaying email addresses on my website (also linked via mailto:).
2. Having an "unprotected" contact form on my website (no captcha
   etc.).

This is all for a static website served via aws S3.

I am afraid of getting hit by spammers.
How could I avoid this in an elegant way (ideally unnoticed by the user)?

Comment: Oh no, spam… how terrible… =P (Spam is not a security risk, so if it’s just your own e-mail address that you’re putting out there, use a mail service with a decent filter and you’ll be fine.)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing you can do Nothing, you have no captcha therefore you are at the mercy of spammers.